# Sending field metadata to client in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want my client to be able to request metadata about a `@RequestMapping`, like the `@Size` and `@Length` values of each field. Does Spring have a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing might be Spring HATEOAS Affordances for HAL forms.

[Spring HATEOAS Affordances](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas-examples/tree/master/affordances)

Responses produce output which includes all the metadata about the request model along with validation rules and method.

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "employees": [...]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees"
    }
  },
  "_templates": {
    "default": {
      "title": null,
      "method": "post",
      "contentType": "",
      "properties":[
        {
          "name": "firstName",
          "required": true
        },
        {
          "name": "id",
          "required": true
        },
        {
          "name": "lastName",
          "required": true
        },
        {
          "name": "role",
          "required": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```